# MySQL + Snow Leopard + 32 Bit + Ruby on Rails = uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes (HELP!)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-snow-leopard

So i'm running Snow Leopard on a BlackBook. I'm attempting to get rake db:migrate to work with this project but I get the MysqlCompat::MysqlRes error. Is there any special way to install or build the gem and/or the actual MySQL binaries themselves to get this to work on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$ sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

You can find your mysql_config with `locate bin/mysql_config` -- and use that path instead of the above if it's different.

If that doesn't work, here's a more complicated answer:

http://accidentaltechnologist.com/apple/fixing-uninitialized-constant-mysqlcompatmysqlres-error-on-snow-leopard/